# Adding partial horizontal lines with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
mydf = read.table(text="
name a b
x 10 15
y 20 25
z 35 45
", header = T)
```

I want to create a plot as follows:

[image: plot example]

I am not able to add horizontal lines from points to the vertical line at x=50. These lines (blue) have been manually drawn in the figure above. I tried following code but it does not work:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(a, b)) + geom_point()+ 
     geom_vline(xintercept=50)+ 
     geom_line(aes(x=50,y=b, group=name))
```

Comment: did you look at `geom_segment`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=50) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=a, xend=50, y=b, yend=b), colour="blue")
```

[image: plot]